# Collection of children's horror stories from the '80s/'90s. One story features a boy being chased through a forest by an undead version of Snow White

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, anthology-book

I am desperately looking for a collection of short horror stories I read as a kid circa 1994. I don't remember much about the rest of the stories, but I remember one in particular:

A kid runs in the forest (as he is being chased ?) and finds refuge in a cottage with seven little men. At the end he lets the creature outside in and we find out that, after being kissed, Snow White became an undead creature, who then devours the boy.

I thought it could have been *[Tales for the Midnight Hour](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/137747.Tales_for_the_Midnight_Hour)* and the likes by Judith Bauer Stamper, but I don't see that story in the books...

Comment: Intriguing. These were tales for kids? I could sure see the undead Snow White being kind of intense for a kid and also I (an adult) would like to read it. Searching for "undead snow white" finds some possibilities which I guess u have seen?

Comment: Have you tried the "Snow White, Blood Red" series edited by Ellen Datlow? They are modern retellings of old folk tales and I think there are six anthologies now, so you might need to dig through them.

Comment: Yes these tales were for kids and pre-teen. I have been down this rabbit hole many times but happy to listen to what you have found if it is in a collection of short stories, as there are many standalone books on the subject. "Snow White, Blood Red" sounds enticing but it's its own series. This was a short story...

Comment: My goodness Googling this leads to [some dark places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow,_Glass,_Apples).

Comment: @AxelleDervauz 'Snow White Blood Red' is a collection of short stories. It now has a series of books, but they're all short stories. Lots and lots and lots of short stories.

Comment: I checked but alas no... I think it one of those golden tales that gets lost...Will check again tomorrow but vol 1 and 2 are a no go.